# How to find the guid of the User Profile Service?

Tags: 2013, powershell

I'm looking into an issue where employees that have already had their accounts decommissioned in Active Directory are displaying in our new starters and birthday web parts after they have left the company.

I believe that this holds the answer: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681014(v=office.15).aspx#disabledUsers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681014%28v=office.15%29.aspx#disabledUsers)

Specifically, using the following:

```
$upa = Get-spserviceapplication <identity>
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upa -GetNonImportedObjects $true
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upa -PurgeNonImportedObjects $true
```

However I don't know how to find the GUID of the User Profile Service - how do I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the below command to get the GUID of the User Profile Service.

```
$upaSAType = "User Profile Service Application"

$upa = Get-SPServiceApplication | where-object {$_.TypeName -eq $upaSAType}

$upa.id
```

Answer (score -2):

Get-SPServiceApplication -Name "User Profile Service Application"